# Call client side jquery popup from code behind in MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

Is it possible to call jquery pop up from code behind in mvc3.
I am doing couple of validations on page through code behind and wants to show the validation success message.
I tried using ScriptManager.RegisterStartCLient but looks like it is deprecated.

Is there anything like this in mvc3?

Comment: You'll probably have to return the validation data from your code behind and have the script on the page read them and generate the messages on the client. What are you using for validation - the MVC3 default one?

Comment: you seem to be confusing MVC with Web Forms. Code Behind is not recommended in MVC and Script Managers don't render.

Comment: I agree code behind is not for MVC. BUt sometime you want to show some messages using jquery after some server side validations etc.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what code behind means in context of ASP.NET MVC. But possibly you should pass your validation message from `Controller` to `View` using `ViewBag`. For example:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
      ViewBag.Message = "Your message";
      return View();
   }
}
```

And then in View render the `script` with razor if message is presence:

```
@if (ViewBag.Message != null) {
   <script>$('#example').some_popup_plugin("@ViewBag.Message")</script>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a property to the viewModel and when I was rendering the view , I checked the property and showed the jquery pop up.

Something like :

```
  @if(Model.IsSUccess)
      showDialog();
```